# numpy.array(list) being slow

Tags: arrays, performance, list, numpy

So I have a list with 5,000,000 integers. And I want to cover the list to a numpy array. I tried following code:

```
numpy.array( list )
```

But it is very slow.

I benchmarked this operation for 100 times and loop over the list for 100 times. There is no much difference.

Any good idea how to make it faster?

Comment: Are you positive your list only contains integers?  What is the dtype of the resulting array?

Comment: Yeah, I'm very positive about that. It is a flat array of image data. So both the input and output arrays are uint8 type

Comment: @user3201090 I made an update to my answer, the previus wasn't fast, this one is

Comment: I'm confused.  You say `list` is a list of integers, but then in comments say it's a `flat array of image data` and `uint8`.  Python integers are not `uint8`.  If it's not a `ndarray`, is is a bytestring`?

Comment: What is 'very slow'?  So slow you see lag when done interactively?  Or slow when converting 1000's of these 'images'?

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I mean every value is a positive integer in the original list, and I want to convert the list to a numpy array with numpy.uint8 values.

Comment: @hpaulj By "slow", I mean it taking the same amount of time as looping over every value in the original list. I suppose it is not the fastest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [cython](/questions/tagged/cython) you can create a function that is definetly faster. But just a warning: It will crash if there are invalid elements inside your list (not-integers or too big integers).

I use the IPython magic here (`%load_ext cython` and `%%cython`), the point is to show how the function looks like - not to show how you can compile Cython code (it's not hard and Cythons "how-to-compile" documentation is quite good).

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython

cimport cython
import numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef to_array(list inp):
    cdef long[:] arr = np.zeros(len(inp), dtype=long)
    cdef Py_ssize_t idx
    for idx in range(len(inp)):
        arr[idx] = inp[idx]
    return np.asarray(arr)
```

And the timings:

```
import numpy as np

def other(your_list):  # the approach from @Damian Lattenero in the other answer
    ret = np.zeros(shape=(len(your_list)), dtype=int)
    np.copyto(ret, your_list)
    return ret

inp = list(range(1000000))
%timeit np.array(inp)
# 315 ms ± 5.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.array(inp, dtype=int)
# 311 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit other(inp)
# 316 ms ± 3.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit to_array(inp)
# 23.4 ms ± 1.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So it's more than 10 times faster.

Comment: Thanks to this performance improvement, I now can process a video with 35 fps and, most importantly, do not have to rewrite thousands lines of code in c++.

Comment: Although it is only about 5 times faster on my mac.

Comment: @Yinan You can also use `cdef np.uint8_t[:] arr = np.zeros(len(inp), dtype=np.uint8)` (requires to `cimport numpy as np` as well as `import numpy as np`). The operation is basically bandwidth-limited so choosing the smallest dtype possible could speed this up by significantly. I'm using windows so long is `int32` on mac it's probably `int64`, so it could explain why yours seems a factor 2 slower. Your "numbers" are twice as long.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fast, I checked the times:

```
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.time()

number = 1
elements = 10000000

your_list = [number] * elements

ret = np.zeros(shape=(len(your_list)))
np.copyto(ret, your_list)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 0.7615997791290283 seconds ---
```

Comment: why would looping over the whole list faster?

Comment: @user3201090 I would say there is no reallocation in the copyto, because `ret` was already allocated and in proper shape, this is why it is fast

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux,  the OP is talking about a previous attempt of mine, with a for loop

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is that really faster than `np.array(your_list)`? I did some timings and it wasn't faster. Note that `np.zeros` gives a `float` array but the question specifies an `int` array.

Comment: @MSeifert I tried this method. It's not faster than np.array(.).

Answer (score 1):

Make a big list of small integers; use the `numpy` crutch:

```
In [619]: arr = np.random.randint(0,256, 5000000)
In [620]: alist = arr.tolist()
In [621]: timeit alist = arr.tolist()     # just for reference
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
```

And time for plain list iteration (doesn't do anything)

```
In [622]: timeit [i for i in alist]
10 loops, best of 3: 193 ms per loop
```

Make an array of specified dtype

```
In [623]: arr8 = np.array(alist, 'uint8')
In [624]: timeit arr8 = np.array(alist, 'uint8')
1 loop, best of 3: 508 ms per loop
```

We can get a 2x improvement with `fromiter`; evidently it does less checking.  `np.array` will work even if the list is a mix of numbers and strings.  It also handles lists of lists etc.

```
In [625]: timeit arr81 = np.fromiter(alist, 'uint8')
1 loop, best of 3: 249 ms per loop
```

The advantage of working with arrays becomes apparent when we do math across the whole thing:

```
In [628]: timeit arr8.sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.93 ms per loop
In [629]: timeit sum(alist)
10 loops, best of 3: 74.4 ms per loop
In [630]: timeit 2*arr8
100 loops, best of 3: 6.89 ms per loop
In [631]: timeit [2*i for i in alist]
1 loop, best of 3: 465 ms per loop
```

It's well known that working with arrays is faster than with lists, but that there is a significant 'startup' overhead.